# is there any way to find the row number where I am selecting in dropdown in Kendo grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, dropdown

[image]In my Kendo grid I want to find the row number where i am making selection in dropdown. So that I cauld change the datepicker editable and focused.

Attaching pic for reference.

[image]

This is the code for kendo field

```
  {
                          field: "md_of_iss",
                          title: "Mode of issue",
                          template: "#= modeName(md_of_iss) #",
                          editor: function (container) {              
                       var input = $('<input id="md_of_iss" name="md_of_iss">');
                              input.appendTo(container);
                              input.kendoDropDownList({
                                  dataTextField: "rsrc_Description",
                                  dataValueField: "md_of_iss",
                                  dataSource: array,
                                  change: function (e) {

                                  }

                              }).appendTo(container);
                          },

                      },
```

Comment: The mode of issue column in white background is a dropdown, it becomes dropdown when hovered, see this answer for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840905/open-kendo-editor-on-hover-also

Comment: Ok, and *when* you want to get the row number, in which event? Change of the dropdown, hover...?

Comment: yes, on change event of dropdown

Comment: And your dropdown is created with the function `categoryDropDownEditor`  as you posted on the other question ?

Comment: this function CategoryDropDownEditor is being used in another page, i have just a similar function

Comment: Well, you need to provide some code, otherwise will be hard to help.

Comment: yes, made the changes in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
change: function (e) {
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
}.bind(input)
```

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ohOWi)

Just [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the `input` to the `change` event context to use it to find the current `tr` index with [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: its giving -1. actually $(input).closest("tr") is not available.

Comment: your demo works fine, but in my project the $(this).parent().length = 0, It seems to be some independent body. So i cant find the row index

Comment: @Spark There is no `$(this).parent().length` in my code or in yours either. I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: can you tell me a way how can i debug the jsfiddle . I could not get the js file that is doing the job

Comment: @Spark sure, just add a [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement anywhere in your code with your developer tools open. [Here's how to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/988624/1267304).

Comment: I want to debug the jsFiddle u gave me. I am not getting a way to debug that

Comment: @Spark dojo.telerik seems to be unstable for me, I can't save a new version, but you can just add `debugger;` after this line `change: function (e) {`. Then you open your dev tools (F12) and hit *Run*. It should stop in your debugger.